# How to check if reflection apis are present or not in our project-Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-9.0-pie

I know this site is for asking the programming questions but I am sorry to say that I have googled a lot but not found If a shortcut/tool for searching the reflection apis present or not in android studio.

As Android P will/may block the reflection apis.

References:

https://github.com/stefan-zobel/streamsupport/issues/2
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/84ms4t/android_p_hidden_api_removal_outrage/

Any help is always appreciated.

Thanks